# How does setInterval work in reactjs (function components)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

I have got some states. I have got one button, which starts `setInterval` 1 second tick interval. Inside this `setInterval` I set these states.

```
let startGame;

const Cat = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState(null);
    let [foodLevel, setFoodLevel] = useState(10);
    let [healthLevel, setHealthLevel] = useState(10);

    const [warning, setWarning] = useState('');
    const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState(0);

    const [value, setValue] = useState('');

    const onChangeHandler = (event) => {
        const { value } = event.target;

        setValue(value);
    };

    const checkZeroFoodLevel = useCallback(() => {
        return foodLevel <= 0;
    }, [foodLevel]);

    const tick = () => {
        startGame = setInterval(() => {
            if (!checkZeroFoodLevel()) {
                setFoodLevel((prevFoodLevel) => prevFoodLevel - 1);
                console.log(foodLevel); //foodLevel=10 every tick
            } else {
                setHealthLevel((prevHealthLevel) => prevHealthLevel - 1);
                console.log(healthLevel);//healthLevel=10 every tick
            }
        }, 1000);

        setIntervalId(startGame);
    };

    const startClickHandler = () => {
        setName(value);
        tick();
    };

    if (healthLevel === 0) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
    
    return(...)
};
```

But when I click on this button, and output in a console my `foodLevel` state inside `setInterval` callback, this state does not update, but in a render is work fine. And when I output that from outside, it is updating as expect.

I found example with `useRef()`:

```
let startGame;

const Cat = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState(null);
    let [foodLevel, setFoodLevel] = useState(10);
    let [healthLevel, setHealthLevel] = useState(10);

    const currentFood = useRef(foodLevel);
    currentFood.current = foodLevel;

    const [warning, setWarning] = useState('');
    const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState(0);

    const [value, setValue] = useState('');

    const onChangeHandler = (event) => {
        const { value } = event.target;

        setValue(value);
    };

    const checkZeroFoodLevel = useCallback(() => {
        return currentFood.current <= 0;
    }, [currentFood]);

    const tick = () => {
        startGame = setInterval(() => {
            if (!checkZeroFoodLevel()) {
                setFoodLevel((prevFoodLevel) => prevFoodLevel - 1);
                console.log(currentFood);
            } else {
                setHealthLevel((prevHealthLevel) => prevHealthLevel - 1);
                console.log(healthLevel);
            }
        }, 1000);

        setIntervalId(startGame);
    };

    const startClickHandler = () => {
        setName(value);
        tick();
    };

    if (healthLevel === 0) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    }

    return (...);
}
```

This is working fine. But I think that it is overhead. If I will have many states, I must create ref for each of them. I think, that it is not correct.
Can somebody explain to me why inside the function `setInterval` a state does not update? Can I do it without using `useRef`?

Comment: If it is working in the render, then is your question `why can't I console.log state directly after setting it?`

Comment: `foodLevel` from the render cycle the interval is started in is closed over in callback scope. The state is updated correctly but you're just logging a stale value from the enclosure. Storing a value into a React ref is a common solution to accessing the current value in a callback like this.

Comment: You could store any number of values in an object saved to a single ref. You could also use `setTimeout` for each tick, reenclosing the current state values you need for conditional tests in the callback.

Comment: @Drew Reese,  Ok. I understand. Thank you!